# What alternatives to R20 bulbs can I use?

Tags: lighting, led

When we bought our house, the lighting fixtures in the ceiling came with R20 bulbs. I know nothing about lighting so I figured that only R20 bulbs are compatible with our fixtures. But I'm realizing that may not be the case.

So what are kinds of bulbs can I use that are interchangeable with R20 bulbs?

More specifically, I'm interested in [Philips' Hue bulbs](http://www2.meethue.com/en-us/)

Are any bulbs from that line compatible with lighting fixtures that accept R20 bulbs?

Answer (score 4):

These would be the equivalent of an R20 flood lamp: 
[image]

R20 is simply a lamp size and style designation. 
R for reflector lamp.
20 for 20 eights of an inch, or 20/8", or 2.5" in diameter.

Just know, standard "A-lamps" will fit similarly to R20 lamps. It's just R lamps are reflector and will concentrate the light basically in one direction, while A lamps glow all around. The design of the fixture will determine what lamps will work best.

Comment: @KhoiVinh And of course observe the fixture wattage limits.